# s3 HeadObject returning object metadata but boto3 Copy Object call fails (NoSuchKey) intermittently

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

According to AWS documentation and stack overflow community, the best way to deal with 404 (NoSuchKey) error for read after right is to call and retry the HeadObject operation for a specific key until it succeeded! Here is my code:

```
# first writing objects into the prefix1 here
...

# copy files from the prefix1 to the prefix2
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix1):

   # this function make sure the specific key is available for read 
   # by calling HeadObject with retries - throwing exception otherwise
   waitForObjectToBeAvaiableForRead(bucketName, obj.key)

   copy_source = {
       "Bucket": bucketName,
       "Key": obj.key
   }
   new_key = obj.key.replace(prefix1, prefix2, 1)
   new_obj = bucket.Object(new_key)
   new_obj.copy(copy_source)
```

This code works most of the time. But very RARELY I am getting this error for `new_obj.copy(copy_source)`:

```
NoSuchKey:An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

However my logs shows the `HeadObject` call returns a successful response after a few retries (which means file is eventually consistent!!!) but the copy operation fails!
Can somebody explain what possibly can be the reason behind this behavior? Appreciate your response.

Comment: S3 is [eventually consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency#:~:text=Eventual%20consistency%20is%20a%20consistency,return%20the%20last%20updated%20value.)

Comment: @jordanm I'm handling the eventually consistency in my code! My question is even after that the copy operation on the object fails with `NoSuchKey` error.